# On form submit check user logged in or not drupal 7

Tags: drupal, authentication

I need your help.
I have drupal 7 cck form which is viewable for anonymous user but when anonymous user fill the form and click on submit i want to show user login form and without page refresh after login  cck form will automatically submit and show thank you message.
I searched a lot for this but i did not get any solution.
Please help me i don't understand how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom module which uses the form_alter hook.  Then for your CCK form, you can check to see if the user is logged in or not and if not, add a username/password fields to the form for the user to fill out.  then add a custom validation function to the form, so that when the form is submitted your validation function attempts to programatically login the user. If login fails then display a form error, else set the global user to the logged in user. so by the time the form hits its submit function the user should be logged in.

So something like this for your custom module:

```
<?php
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id){
    global $user;
    //only for the form we are looking for, and if the user is anonymous
    if (($form_id == 'my_form_id') && ($user->uid==0)){
        $form['login']  = array(
            '#type' => 'fieldset',
            '#title'    => 'Login',
        );
        $form['login']['username'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => 'Username',
            '#required' => true,
        );
        $form['login']['password'] = array(
            '#type' => 'password',
            '#title'    => 'Password',
            '#required' => true,
        );

        $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_my_form_validate';
    }
}

function mymodule_my_form_validate(&$form,&$form_state){
    global $user;

    //stop from re-login if there were other validation errors
    if ($user->uid == 0){
        $username = $form_state['values']['username'];
        $password = $form_state['values']['password'];
        //authenticate the user (attempt to login)
        if ($uid = user_authenticate($username,$password)){
            $user = user_load($uid);
            //finalize login
            user_login_finalize(array('name'=>$username,'pass'=>$password));
        }else{
            form_set_error('username','Invalid username or password');
        }
    }
}
```